# How to get the averages of values in a table

Tags: kql

I'm trying to get some information out of log analytics and I want to know if I can extract the average of values from different lines.

For example, let's say I have a table that goes like this:

```
.create table customer (name: string, month: int, salary: long, living: long)

.ingest inline into table customer<
gabriel, 1, 1000, 500
gabriel, 2, 1000, 800 
gabriel, 3, 2500, 800
gabriel, 4, 2500, 800
John, 1, 1500, 1000
John, 2, 1500, 500
John, 3, 1500, 500
John, 4, 1500, 1200
jina, 1, 3000, 1000
jina, 2, 3000, 1000
jina, 3, 3000, 1500
jina, 4, 5000, 2500
```

Here we have the simplest possible table to explain my inquire, we're listing the salary and living expenses of each customer per month (namely month 1, month 2, 3 and 4).

Then I want to know the average salary and living expenses of gabriel, John and Jina in this period of 4 months.

The actual query I want to apply this is a tad more complicated but this is enough to explain my problem

Comment: Using datatable() as in the answer will make the question simpler to write and to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
datatable(name:string, month:int, salary:long, living:long)[
'gabriel', 1, 1000, 500,
'gabriel', 2, 1000, 800,
'gabriel', 3, 2500, 800,
'gabriel', 4, 2500, 800,
'John', 1, 1500, 1000,
'John', 2, 1500, 500,
'John', 3, 1500, 500,
'John', 4, 1500, 1200,
'jina', 1, 3000, 1000,
'jina', 2, 3000, 1000,
'jina', 3, 3000, 1500,
'jina', 4, 5000, 2500]
| summarize Avg_Salary=avg(salary), Avg_Expenses=avg(living) by name
```

**Result:**

```
name     Avg_Salary  Avg_Expenses
gabriel  1750        725
John     1500        800
jina     3500        1500
```

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for, thank you